# $a-c = \frac{b}{2},\ a-b = \frac{c}{6},\ b+c = 32$ find $a$ =?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am getting frustrated as I am fighting with this. Please help. I know

$$
    2a = b+2c \\
    6a = 6b+c
$$
but after this i get confuse what to do next ?

Comment: Can you make a combination of those two equations that gives you equal multiples of $b$ and $c$?

Comment: Thank you all for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have
$$2a = b+2c \\
6a = 6b+c
$$

We would like to have equal multiples of $b$ and $c$ (because we know what $b+c$  is) but there is an imbalance currently. But hey, we can fix that but multiplying the top equation by 5:
$$\begin{align}10a &= 5b+10c \\
6a &= 6b+c \\ \hline
16a &= 11b+11c
\end{align}$$

then $16a = 11 \times 32$ and $a=22$

Then $2a=b+2c \implies 44=32+c$ and $c=12$

Finally $a-b=\frac{12}{6}$ and $b=20$

Answer (score 0):

$$a =22$$
    $$a-c = b/2$$ 
Therefore:
$$b = 2(a-c)\\a- b =c/6$$
Therefore:
$$c = 6(a-b)$$
sub in the values of $c$ and $b$ in the equations:
$$a - 6a + 6b = b/2\\
2a - 12a +12b = b\\
11b = 10a$$

$$c = 6a - 12a +12c\\
6a = 11c \\ 
b+c = 32\\
11b + 11c = 32 x 11\\
11b = 10a\\
11c = 6a$$
therefore:
$$10a + 6a = 32 x 11\\
16a = 352\\
a =22$$

Comment: sorry could someone please edit my answer, i am new to this and i don't know how to set out the format correctly yet. sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

Instead, let's start with what you had before, but let's keep all variables on one side:

$$
a - \frac{b}{2} - c = 0 \\
a - b - \frac{c}{6} = 0 \\
b + c = 32
$$

Try adding the last two equations together. Then try adding the first two equations together.

To add two equations together in a meaningful way, you add their left sides together to make a new left side and their right sides together to get a new right side. You can do the same thing for subtraction.

Watch what happens when you differ the first two equations:

$$
a - \frac{b}{2} - c \\
-(a - b - \frac{c}{6}) \\
= \frac{b}{2} - \frac{5c}{6} = 0
$$

You can then solve for $b$ or $c$:

$$
\frac{b}{2} = \frac{5c}{6} \\
6b = 10c \\
b = \frac{5}{3} c
$$

Comment: This is not a full answer, this is just a hint. But I hope it puts you in the right direction for figuring out how to handle systems of equations.

Comment: I am weak in math but don't always want to be weak.
I know that the answer ( a = 22, c = 12 and b = 20 )But I want to know the process.


http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a-c+%3D+b%2F2%2C+a-b+%3D+c%2F6%2C+b%2Bc+%3D+32%2C+find+a+%3D+%3F

Comment: This is the process. You have to use all 3 equations at once. And you have to operate on them just like they are numbers. This is how you manipulate systems of equations. From where I left off, you now have a solution for $b$. Replace all instances of $b$ with $\frac{5}{3}c$ in your original three equations and then try solving for $c$ with one of them.

Answer (score 0):

From the first equation it follows that $6a=3b+6c$. So, using the second equation, you get: $3b+6c=6b+c\Rightarrow 5c=3b\Rightarrow c=\frac{3b}{5}\Rightarrow b+\frac{3b}{5}=32\Rightarrow \frac{8b}{5}=32\Rightarrow b=20\Rightarrow c=12$, using any of the first two equations, it follows that $a=22$.

Comment: From the first equation it follows that 6a=3b+6c. How ? I didn't get it.

Comment: You got to the fact that $2a=b+2c$. Multiplying both sides with $3$, it follows that $6a=3(b+2c)\Rightarrow 6a=3b+6c$.

Comment: I was not even looking it properly, feeling dumb.  Ok I got it. Thank you Iulia.